# Persistant storage values handling in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, persistent, flash-memory

I have a QSPI flash on my embedded board.
I have a driver + process "Q" to handle reading and writing into.
I want to store variables like SW revisions, IP, operation time, etc.

I would like to ask for suggestions how to handle the different access rights to write and read values from user space and other processes.

I was thinking to have file for each variable. Than I can assign access rights for those files and process Q can change the value in file if value has been changed. So process Q will only write into and other processes or users can only read.

But I don't know about writing. I was thinking about using message queue or zeroMQ and build the software around it but i am not sure if it is not overkill. But I am not sure how to manage access rights anyway.

What would be the best approach? I would really appreciate if you could propose even totally different approach.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will probably be downvoted / flagged due to the "Please suggest an X" nature.

That said, if a file per variable is what you're after, you might want to look at implementing a FUSE file system that wraps your SPI driver/utility "Q" (or build it into "Q" if you get to compile/control source to "Q").  I'm doing this to store settings in an EEPROM on a current work project and its turned out nicely.  So I have, for example, a file, that when read, retrieves 6 bytes from EEPROM (or a cached copy) provides a MAC address in std hex/colon-separated notation.

The biggest advantage here, is that it becomes trivial to access all your configuration / settings data from shell scripts (e.g. your `init` process) or other scripting languages.

Another neat feature of doing it this way is that you can use `inotify` (which comes "free", no extra code in the fusefs) to create applications that efficiently detect when settings are changed.

A disadvantage of this approach is that it's non-trivial to do atomic transactions on multiple settings and still maintain normal file semantics.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about! But didn't know about FUSE. Thanks! But what do you mean about "still maintain normal file semantics"? Could you give an example? I was planning to have separate file for every variable so if you read a file you exactly know the value.And if transactions are kind of atomic its big plus. Regarding writing I am planing to have cached copy and do writings in batch based on specific events.

Comment: Well for example, say you have addr, netmask, and gateway for a static IP.  Ideally, you could update them all as "set" in a single transaction and then have a network manager thing get a single inotify that all 3 changed and call the appropriate `ioctl`.  What you *can* do, is add a separate file, e.g. called "update_ifconfig" that must be written and then inotify watch just that file.  But then writing gets slightly less clean/straightforward and still doesn't eliminate race conditions if two processes try to write at once.

Comment: For configuration that changes infrequently, it's not a big deal.  Where my current solution falls a little short is when I have a single process with a few dozen settings, and I'd *like* to have them all split out into a file system for quick access in testing/scripting, but at the same time don't want dozens of file change notifications and dozens of restarts to the application that uses the settings.

Comment: Now I understand, but if I will write only by one process and only "read" by multiple ones I could probably eliminate race conditions at least.

Comment: How did you figure out to run fuse as non root user? @Brian McFarland

Comment: I don't.... maybe some of the config options in /etc/fuse.conf, used by [mount.fuse](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) would help?

Comment: Ok so you run it as a root. I was just curious because I read somewhere I shouldn't run it as a root because it could create security holes.